# Match everything in brackets after a specific character

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
$text = 'These are my cards. They are {{Archetype|Agumon}} and {{Fire|Gabumon}}'
```

I'm trying to replace all instances of occurrences like `{{Archetype|Agumon}}` into `[Agumon]`.

I've been struggling to get my head around it and have come up with this so far:

```
$string = preg_replace('#\{\{(.*?)\}\}#', '[$1]', $text);
```

This results in:

> These are my cards. They are [Archetype|Agumon] and [Fire|Gabumon]

So I am currently matching the full text found in between the double curly brackets.

I thought it would be something like this: `\|(.*?)` to get the match after the `|` character in the curly brackets but to no avail.

Comment: You probably want `\{\{[^}]*\|([^}]*)\}\}`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zwpx6R/1).

Comment: Thank you! That does it. Also thank you for the helpful link which explains how it works, that is very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
\{\{[^}]*\|([^}]*)\}\}
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zwpx6R/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

- `\{\{` - Match "{{" literally.
- `[^}]*` - Greedily match zero or more characters other than '}'.
- `\|` - Match a pipe character.
- `([^}]*)` - Match zero or more characters other than '}' and capture them in group 1.
- `\}\}` - Match "}}" literally.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```php
preg_replace('/{{(?:(?!{|}})[^|]*\|(.*?))}}/s', '[$1]', $text)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/j9TeKy/2). It will support `{` and `}` in the part before the pipe.

**Explanation**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  {{                       '{{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      {                        '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      }}                       '}}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^|]*                    any character except: '|' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  }}                       '}}'
```

[**PHP code**](https://tio.run/##Jc7RCoIwFMbxe5/iBMI2CaXbLIY39QLdmcVaBxekHqZBsu3Zl9jVB7/v5k@GYjxIMpQk6YTfCY7ALgZHBGURuhm0ss8xh8XmlZyrrDY4zYS@aj/d0IcAqn8ux@ll0Z/V44@sTFCbAchie7dIb6WRs8I5LvdcbpwPQdQ332RXz/NMChFCMbItsDrdNcuuOaKM8Qc):

```php
$text = 'These are my cards. They are {{Archetype|Agumon}} and {{Fire|Gabumon}}';
echo preg_replace('/{{(?:(?!{|}})[^|]*\|(.*?))}}/s', '[$1]', $text);
```

**Results**: `These are my cards. They are [Agumon] and [Gabumon]`